# Custom widget in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, datepicker, timepicker

I need to customize my Android application for ancient people, which typically have vision problems.

If is not so difficult increase the font size of `EditText` or `TextView` fields, I can't say the same about the `TimePicker` , `DatePicker` or `NumberPicker`. For these widget I think that I can't change the size. Right?

Someone knows how can I solve this problem? I need to create a custom plugin? If so, where I can found materials for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is call "Custom Widget" or "Custom View"

FYI : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html